# How to change row colour depending on due date in a cell

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, conditional-formatting

I need a whole row to be red if the date in column C is older than today()

I have tried this basic formula

```
=C2:C<TODAY()
```

but that makes every row that is still empty also red.

So how to add basically "if a cell in column C is empty, do nothing"?
I can go around it by adding another condition that says when it's empty, make it white and put it above the red condition but I want to avoid unnecessary complications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=AND($C1<>""; $C1 < TODAY())
```

[image: 0]

Comment: YES! Thank you as always, you perfectly helped